# Data Attributes, asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had a phone number in which the entered data should be only numeric. I would like to differentiate it in Model some thing like..

```
[Required]
//i want to place some thing here//
public string PhoneNumber
{
    get;
    set;

}
```

Can any one please help me to find the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a `[RegularExpressionAttribute][1]`

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"\d+")]
public string PhoneNumber
{
    get;
    set;

}
```

That regular expresion just allows numbers (like you asked) but you could use a more complex regular expression to allow a certain format of phone number if you want to be more strict, for example see http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7

Answer (score 1):

Try the data annotation extension (`NumericAttribute`)

http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx